# Letting users generate XML product feed through my website

Tags: javascript, php, xml, wordpress, plugins

My problem is that i need to let users create an XML feed with all my sites products (including photos and prices) so that they can then upload it to their sites. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress feeds 
Refer the following plugin for products
WooCommerce Product Feed Manager – WordPress plugin ...
https://wordpress.org/plugins/best-woocommerce-feed/

Comment: Im trying to display the feed generator on the frontend so that plugin is not quite helpful! Plus you have to go pro to generate more than 50 products! thanks for your reply though.